# How do i connect to a given ip from database with specified name , password, and port

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Like the title says. I have to connect to a database with some IP address, port , login name and login password.

I tried using the Server Explorer in the Visual studio 2015. The problem i have is that  don't know how to add the port number in the connection. Shall the port number be added like **ip:port or ip,port** in the server name tab of Visual Server Explorer?

Also is there anyway to do this in the connectionStrings tag of WebConfig?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionName1" connectionString="DataSource=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server uses comma as the port separator for connections, for example:

```
DataSource=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx,xxxx
```

You can see more examples [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer and the link provided.